# Sublime ignores syntax specific tab size for new files

Tags: tabs, sublimetext3, indentation

I am using the latest Sublime Text 3, and have this in a syntax specific config for JavaScript

```
{
    "translateTabsToSpaces": true,
    "tabSize": 2
}
```

But every time I create a new file, it defaults to 4 spaces.  I have tried adding `"detect_indentation": true` but then ALL files started to be 4 spaces for tabs, ignoring the syntax specific config even further.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your settings names are incorrect. Sublime uses `snake_case` variables, not `camelCase`. Your `JavaScript.sublime-settings` file should look like this:

```js
{
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "tab_size": 2
}
```

To see all of the available settings, select **`Preferences → Settings—Default`**.

Comment: I don't know where I got the camelCase settings from.  Thanks!